# Run a class file from a spring boot jar

Tags: spring-boot

I have a spring boot application jar

```
BOOT-INF/  
  classes/  
     com.package.name/  
        SpringEntry.class  
        integration/  
             Integration.class   
  lib/  
     MANIFEST.MF  
META-INF/
```

org.springframework.boot.loader/

Both files have the main method.
I'm trying to execute the Integration.class from the command line.

The manifest file has the following lines

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: *****
Implementation-Version: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
Built-By: ****
Implementation-Vendor-Id: *****
Spring-Boot-Version: 2.0.3.RELEASE
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
Start-Class: com.package.name.SpringEntry
Spring-Boot-Classes: BOOT-INF/classes/
Spring-Boot-Lib: BOOT-INF/lib/
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_181
Implementation-URL: *****
```

I want to run the integration file once the code has been deployed. from the command line. I can't hit an API to execute the functionalities because it is a non web application.

To run springapplication.jar, I have to run

```
java -jar springapplication.jar
```

How do I run the integration file from from the command line after I run this command to execute the code on the integration class?

Let me know if you need additional information regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

But editing the JAR and changing the manifest content (which is not advised as not reproducible and error prone), you cannot.

Here you specified :

> Start-Class: com.package.name.SpringEntry

So Spring Boot used that class as spring boot start class.
And you don't have a known parameter to specify another class from the command line once the JAR was created.

As quick alternative, you can specify this information in the spring boot maven plugin when it repackages your application :

```
mvn clean package -Dspring-boot.run.main-class=integration.Integration.class
```

You could also use a Maven profile that also changes the built jar name to distinguish them clearly.

A more robust and configuration at runtime way alternative would to move the specific declaration/logic defined in these Spring Boot classes in configuration classes relying on `@Profile` : `@Profile("default")` and `@Profile("integration")` or more simply `@Profile("!integration")` and `@Profile("integration")`